# git merge branches but only accept changes to specific path

Tags: git, svn, version-control, merge

Sometime ago I've started to use git svn. Now I've some features implement in branch A I would like to merge to branch B. Branch A and B are structed as below: (note, this are not submodules in project sense).

```
A 
  /module0
  /module1
  .
  .
  .
  /module15
B 
  /module0
  /module1
  /module2
  /module3
```

Branch B is a fresh branch created from a subversion branch.

```
git checkout remote/... -b B
```

Those modules 0-3 in svn remote branch and svn trunk (A) have been split years ago and manually patched (no svn merge info) so there are numerous changes.

My goal is to merge some changes from module0 from A to B. Preferably via git merge so later on it's easier to merge future changes. I've already discovered merging a single directory doesn't work out, so here is what I did:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

which results in HUUUUUUUUUUGE conflicts and extra 12 modules in branch B.

I'm uncertain how to correctly proceed from here.

I've `git rm -rf moduleX` all unneccessary module and tried to get rid of changes in module1-4 via

```
git checkout --ours /moduleX
```

But git reports still merge conflicts in these modules and also some files as modified, because they are only changed in A, but I don't want those changes.

Alternativly I've thought about cherry picking, but this seems rather painful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your method is very close.  I'd change the `git checkout` to read:

```
git checkout HEAD -- moduleX
```

This checks out the "ours" version of every file, including every successfully auto-merged file.  Using `--ours` will, I think, only restore "conflicted" files to version `B`.  (Also, you can use `B` or `HEAD`, whichever is easier; they resolve to the same SHA-1, since you're merging into branch `B` so that `HEAD` is just another name for `B`.)

Check `git status` as often as needed to make sure you've taken only the pieces you want.